# `Module not found: 'vue-server-renderer'`

Tags: npm, webpack, vuejs2, module, vue-test-utils

I am trying to compile my vue component to unit test it.

I added the `import { render } from "@vue/server-test-utils";` line at the beginning of my test file. I also run the command `npm i --save-dev @vue/server-test-utils` which completed successfully. I checked the `node_modules` folder that the dependency was indeed installed.

[image]

But still when I run the test file I am getting the error:

> WEBPACK  Failed to compile with 1 error(s)
> Error in ./node_modules/@vue/server-test-utils/dist/vue-server-test-utils.js
> Module not found: 'vue-server-renderer'

[Here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/1734) I found a similar issue. I tried adding the

```
chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module
      .rule('vue')
      .use('vue-loader')
      .tap(options => {
        options.isServerBuild = false;
        return options;
      });
  }
```

to my webpack config, but it did not help.

I am using Vue 2. Maybe someone happened to stumble across this issue and knows a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm install --save-dev vue-server-renderer @vue/server-test-utils` worked.

It seems that we have to install the two packages: the `vue-server-renderer` and then the `@vue/server-test-utils`.